# Automatically Create a New Copy of a Public Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive

Our company just created a new template for website planning. It is available as a Google sheet. We've also added instruction on how to create a copy for themselves. Like open the document, Go to File -> Make a Copy. However, we still get many requests asking for access.

Is there a way to automatically create a new copy for the user when he/she click on the link, instead of the view only file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

On the spreadsheet URL, replace `/edit` by `/copy`

## Extended answer

The Google Sheets spreadsheet URL looks like the following

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aAKaVc-eUBwmwCFwX4q4vLtubDzE_81kOTWgbmz4FvU/edit#gid=0`

Replace `/edit` and the following characters by `/copy`

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aAKaVc-eUBwmwCFwX4q4vLtubDzE_81kOTWgbmz4FvU/copy`